# PowerShell and M2MQTT

Tags: powershell, mqtt

I'm trying to create a simple MQTT client in PowerShell to receive some messages from a broker. This broker is using a non standard port.

To do that, I followed the instructions I found at https://jackgruber.github.io/2019-06-05-ps-mqtt/

When using the example's code it's working fine but when I'm trying to specify a port like

```
$MqttClient = [uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient]("mqtt-broker.net",41383)
```

it throws the error:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient".
At line:1 char:1
+ $MqttClient = [uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient]("ext.mqtt.drya ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'd need to construct the object, not just cast it.

Try:

```
[upLibrary.Networking.m2mqtt.mqttclient]::new("mqtt-broker.net",41383)
```

Comment: Hi! This throws:

 PS C:\Windows\system32> $MqttClient = [uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient]::new("ext.mqtt.dryad.app",31383)
Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:1
+ $MqttClient = [uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient]::new("ext.mqtt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest